# Matlab VideoReader on Ubuntu, quicktime codec

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, 64-bit, codec, quicktime

## **My problem**

I am using latest Matlab (r2014a) on a 64 bits Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have tried to load a video with VideoReader, but as soon as I do it an error pops out:

> "Error using VideoReader/init (line 457)
>
> The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system:  video/quicktime"

Just to clarify, this I how I call it:

```
VideoReader('video/BigBang.mp4');
```

## **What I have tried**

I have read almost all pages regarding matlab, quicktime, codecs, and ubuntu, and so far I haven't been able to make it work.

**So far I've done and checked:**

- Ubuntu is able to play that video file (.mp4) on its own
- It is also able to play any .mp4 or quicktime labeled video (be it from browser or downloaded)
- Installed gstreamer-*, at least all of which I know of
- Tried adding mc3man repository and fetching from there, nothing

I'm really lost here and don't have any clue on what could be going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the output of the following: `info = mmfileinfo('video/BigBang.mp4');v = info.Video;v`

Comment: It is throwing the same error: `Error using mmfileinfo (line 70)
The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system:
 video/quicktime`. I have also tried (just in case) to run it as root, `sudo matlab`, but it makes no difference at all.

Comment: @georg it may be useful to say I am running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 14.04, i forgot to mention it on the post. I'll edit it now

Comment: I guess you have already checked that it is not a 32bit vs. 64bit codec issue, didn't you? Another thing to try: the [videoio toolbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoio/). On linux this library uses ffmpeg as a backend. It is fast and quite reliable though no longer maintained. (I guess also because Matlab improved its internal video tools). I am [still using](http://www.mathworks.at/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35119-videoioplayer) that lib, though I must admitt that I am still on Matlab 2010b.

Comment: @georg I have, and it doesn't seem to be codec bits related. I'd rather not use external toolboxes, as it's for some university projects and our professor I supposed to be able to run it. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I'd like to explain how, but I really have no clue. After several upgrades, dist-upgrades, ppa's added, etc. I got it to work.

I hope if anyone finds this can at least use some of the comments to help out.